# Running Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook but getting kernel error

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Here is the error log that I get when I click on Kernel Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in 
_execute result = await result
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 72, in post type=mtype))
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site 
packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session 
self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
value = future.result()
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel 
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 
259, in start_kernel**kw)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, 
in _launch_kernel return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 
138, in launch_kernel proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/Users/Brahmbha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

'/Users/Brahmbha/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py3/bin/python': 
   '/Users/Brahmbha/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py3/bin/python'

Comment: Can you include any relevant code that caused the problem?

Comment: The only code was a single line in the notebook a print statement that read print("Hi Anaconda")

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your jupyter notebook could be trying to use a python enviroment that has been moved or deleted.

Try this in cmd or anaconda:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

See this thread for more:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4079